# ReferenceError: mock is not defined Javascript

Tags: javascript, jsmockito

Main js file that starts everything:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>InterfaceTest</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/angular/bower-angular-mocks/master/angular-mocks.js"></script>

  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/qunit/qunit-2.0.0.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.4.min.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/danielfm/jshamcrest/master/src/jshamcrest.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/cleishm/jsmockito/master/src/jsmockito.js"></script>

  <script src="Interface.js" ></script>
  <script src="InterfaceTest.js" ></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="qunit"></div>
  <div id="qunit-fixture"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

InterfaceTest:

```
QUnit.test("mockitoTest", function(assert) {
    var mockedObject = mock(Array);
    when(mockedObject).get(1).thenReturn("hello world");
    alert(mockedObject.get(1));
});
```

I need to use Jquery, Hamcrest, and JsMockito to make a bunch of unit tests for Interface (doesn't matter what's in it).

The error I get:

```
Died on test #1     at file:///C:/Internship/JavaScript/Qunit/InterfaceTest.js:1:7: mock is not defined@ 
Source:     
ReferenceError: mock is not defined
    at Object.<anonymous> (file:///C:/Internship/JavaScript/Qunit/InterfaceTest.js:2:21)
```

I'm sure it's something obvious, but I've included Mockito as a dependency so I don't know why it says mock is not defined. My assumption is that

```
 <script `type="text/javascript" src="https://rawgit.com/cleishm/jsmockito/master/src/jsmockito.js"></script>
```

must be wrong.

(i saw on another stackoverflow post that if you post the github link on https://rawgit.com/ then you can include it as the src, so that's where those links are coming from)

Answer (score 1):

When I ran your code I saw the error `Can not set mock of undefined` and pointed to the `angular-mocks.js` file.

The file `angular-mocks.js` is expecting angular, but you do not load angular.

Comment: I included that because I saw a similar question here and the chosen answer was that you have to include the angular-mocks.js file so I included it, but wasn't really sure why. How do I load angular? Thanks so much, I've been stuck on this for longer than I care to admit..